# Images not showing up in Jellybean, work fine in all other releases

Tags: android, image, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have a game that uses some custom buttons that automatically resize to fit the screen horizontally.  The images contained in the button display fine in all android versions up to and including 4.0.3. However suddenly on jellybean, they quit displaying. The buttons still work, the images just don't display.

```
 <LinearLayout
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:gravity="bottom"
 android:layout_weight="0.55"
 android:id="@+id/dicemenu">

 <com.surreall.yacht.SquareButton        
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dip"          
    android:layout_weight="1"
>
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/die1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"          
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_margin="9dp" 
    />

  </com.surreall.yacht.SquareButton>

  <com.surreall.yacht.SquareButton        
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dip"          
    android:layout_weight="1"
>
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/die2"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"          
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_margin="9dp" 
    />

  </com.surreall.yacht.SquareButton>

   <com.surreall.yacht.SquareButton         
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dip"          
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/die3"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"          
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_margin="9dp"
    />

  </com.surreall.yacht.SquareButton>
  <com.surreall.yacht.SquareButton         
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dip"          
    android:layout_weight="1"
>
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/die4"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"          
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_margin="9dp" 
    />

  </com.surreall.yacht.SquareButton>
  <com.surreall.yacht.SquareButton         
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dip"          
    android:layout_weight="1"
>
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/die5"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"          
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_margin="9dp" 
    />

  </com.surreall.yacht.SquareButton>
```

Comment: i also had to face same problem but i still could not get a solution for that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might not quite be the "fix" I was looking for, but I found I was using .gif files for my images and i guess that is not recommended for android. It is suggested to use .png instead, I switched and images are showing up ok now...

Comment: yeah .gif is the problem but other versions support for .gif. Is this a bug in jellybean ?

Answer (score 4):

try this before using your ImageView

```
       myImageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

hope this helps your problem..