# Code not Working in Android 4.1.1

Tags: android, android-layout

I am doing something very basic like adding a button to screen. The code works great in Andorid 2.3 but not working in Android 4.1.1.

```
RelativeLayout mainLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
mainLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


ImageView titleView = new ImageView(this);
Bitmap _bitmap = returnScaledBitmap(R.drawable.headertext, display.getWidth()*50/100,display.getHeight()*15/100);
titleView.setImageBitmap(_bitmap);
titleView.setId(R.drawable.headertext);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textLayout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
textLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
titleView.setPadding(display.getWidth()*35/100, display.getWidth()*1/100,display.getWidth()*1/100,display.getWidth()*1/100);
titleView.setLayoutParams(textLayout);

mainLayout.addView(titleView);
setContentView(mainLayout);
```

This code is running fine on HTC EVO 4G which is 2.3.3. But not on Samsung Galaxy S3 which is running 4.1.1. Here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.myorg"
    android:versionCode="6"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
     >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:logo="@drawable/icon" android:debuggable="false">
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".splash" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".homepage"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>
    </application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by it's "not working in Android 4.1.1"? What does the code doe? What do you *want* to do?

Comment: In Android 2.3.3 I see the ImageView being displayed on screen. There is nothing on screen with android 4.1.1

Comment: This suggestion doesn't exactly fix your problem. I just find the name `textLayout` confusing for two reasons: 1) you are using it with an ImageView, not a TextView, and 2) it's not a layout. Maybe `titleParams` would be a more appropriate name.

Comment: Sorry are you using physical devices or emulators to test? Please post your Manifest as well.

Comment: I added the Manifext.xml file. It is on physical device.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not really clear, however I think you are doing this wrong:
`mainLayout.addView(titleView);` I think you wanted to write `textLayout.addView(titleView);`

Comment: Sorry about the way I added the code. I have added the clear code now.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem and after hours of trying different things, this was the only thing that worked for me:

try this before using your ImageView (you may also have to set your minSDKVersion to at least 11 in your manifest).

```
myImageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

i got the solution from a user here, dicenice, on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400909/images-not-showing-up-in-jellybean-work-fine-in-all-other-releases/14928114#14928114) thread